# Creating a network with 1 windows pc and 1 laptop using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have a laptop which uses ubuntu 14.04 and one laptop that uses windows 7.Both are connected to the same router.I want the laptop using ubuntu to have administrator rights on the one with windows 7, so I can use commands to shut it down and more.Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, I'm a user of `NoMachine` which helps at remote desktop connections between various Operating Systems. That way You can control Your Win7 from Ubuntu (window or fullscreen) as its' mouse, keyboard and screen would be connected to Win7. I've even managed to do from Internet and send wake up request to Win7 :) . But if You want just to shut the Win7 down there may be less advanced way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting up an [SSH server on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows), then use the [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) Windows command to [run commands as an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8249705/2072269).

Answer (score 0):

Samba tools should be able to do a shutdown on the windows machine, if the account you are using has remote shutdown rights:

```
    net rpc shutdown -Uadministrator%password -f -C "Reason for shutdown" -S mymachine
    net rpc shutdown -Uadministrator%password -f -C "because I can..." -I xx.yy.zz.aa
```

There are some other things you can do with that, see the manpage of the net command.

But if you want full control of the windows machine your best choice still is rdesktop. Given you have a Pro version of Windows, that doesn't withhold the remote connection capability from you. In that case, you could alternatively install a [VNC](http://tightvnc.com) server on the windows machine and use that to connect to your desktop.